# Java iterate over map twice before deciding whether to remove an object

Tags: java, iterator

I have a map of Object string.
I need to iterate over it twice before deciding whether to remove it or not.

```
protected void removeDayOutOfRangeObjects(Map<Object, String> objects, Calendar[] clientTimeRange) {
        String currentPartOfWeek = null;
        for(Calendar range: clientTimeRange){
            int dayOfWeek = range.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
            if(1 == dayOfWeek || 7 == dayOfWeek) {
                currentPartOfWeek = "weekends";
            } else {
                currentPartOfWeek = "weekdays";
            }
            Iterator<Map.Entry<Object,String>> iter = objects.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<Object,String> entry = iter.next();

                if(currentPartOfWeek.matches(entry.getValue())){
                    continue;
                } else {
                    iter.remove();  // I need to remove the object only if true for both entries in the Calendar array  
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your question *"How can I iterate it only once to get the same thing?"*

Comment: Example I have Calendar array with 2 entries. One is a weekend day and one is a week day. I need to remove the entry from the hashmap only if both entries match

Comment: Hello, it is still unclear what exactly you want. Can you give a concrete example of input and output you expect?

Comment: Example I have Calendar array with 2 entries. One is a weekend day and one is a week day. I need to remove the entry from the hashmap ONLY if both entries are weekends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution would be to reverse the order of the loops. Have the outer loop iterate over the `Map` entries, and the inner loop iterate over the array. In the inner loop, set some flag to true the first time your `currentPartOfWeek.matches(entry.getValue())` is `false` (or `true`, it wasn't clear from your question when you want to remove the entry), and only remove that entry if that flag is true.

This way you only iterate once over the `Map`.

Basically, it will look like this:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Object,String>> iter = objects.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Object,String> entry = iter.next();
    boolean remove = false;
    for(Calendar range: clientTimeRange) {
        if (someCondition) {
            if (remove) {
                iter.remove();
            } else {
                remove = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this relies on having two elements in your `clientTimeRange` array. If there are more elements, you should adjust the logic accordingly (i.e. decide when you want to remove the entry - after two elements of the array match the current Map entry? after all the elements of the array match the current entry?).

Comment: Example I have Calendar array with 2 entries. One is a weekend day and one is a week day. I need to remove the entry from the hashmap ONLY if both entries are weekends

Comment: @OneXer my answer should work. Just replace "someCondition" with the logic you use to determine if to remove an entry. It will only be removed if the condition is true for both elements of the array.